# Do I need linux-update-symlinks to update /vmlinuz after installing a custom kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, deb

Following the [instruction](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-official) I built and installed a custom kernel (and I will keep the old kernel as well)

```
# apt-get install linux-source-4.19
$ tar xaf /usr/src/linux-source-4.19.tar.xz
$ cd linux-source-4.19
$ make localmodconfig
$ make LOCALVERSION=-custom bindeb-pkg
$ dpkg -i ../linux-image-4.19.98-custom_4.19.98-custom-1_amd64.deb
```

After reboot with the new kernel I saw the /vmlinuz and /initrd.img did not get updated with new kernel path and I have to run

```
$ linux-update-symlinks install 4.19.98-custom /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.98-custom
```

is it intended that linux-update-symlinks did not get called during kernel installation?

and what is the general purpose of the symbolic links /vmlinuz and /initrd.img? they are not really necessary for the default GRUB setup.

```
# /etc/kernel-img.conf 
do_symlinks = yes
do_bootloader = no
do_initrd = yes
link_in_boot = no
```